# inserting JS variables into html tag

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to insert a JS variable in html tags and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. The movie does not load. Here is my code:

```
var moviePath = "images/main.swf";    
<script>document.write('<PARAM name="movie" value="' + moviePath + '">')</script>
```

Comment: What isn't working? Is moviePath defined? It doesn't seem like it from the snippet you gave...

Comment: What do you mean by "insert a JS variable?" Do you mean to [concatenate the string](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html#conc)? What you have looks fine, assuming `moviePath` has been defined elsewhere. Are you seeing any errors?

Comment: Is moviePath defined? What happens and how does it differ from your expectations? Why are you using document.write and not DOM functions?

Comment: If this is the only JavaScript code on the page, then there are many things you are doing wrong. If not, please post some more code.

Comment: Yes moviePath is set to the path and name of the movie.

Comment: Is the PARAM tag being added within an OBJECT tag?  Also, you may want to check out swfobject for inserting swf srcs into a page when the swf URL is not static. http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

Comment: This is the line where I need to use a JS variable. The rest is working fine until I use the JS var.

Comment: Try using Firebug to look at the results of the DOM during/after this code runs.  Your code could be running after the DOM loads, meaning this parameters was not set when the movie tried to start.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your var seems to be outside of your script..?

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var moviePath = "images/main.swf";
    document.write('<param name="movie" value="' + moviePath + '">');
</script>
```